# Scaling scene doesn't scale area of buttons

Tags: button, scaling, sprite-kit

In an attempt to scale a scene for a 3.5 inch iPhone to a 4 inches Phone I used the code

-(void)createSceneContents {

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(result.height == 480)
    {
    }
    if(result.height == 568)
    {
        [self runAction:[SKAction scaleXBy:1 y:1.2 duration:0]];
    }
}
```

It scales the scene close enough for my liking however I've come across a problem with clicking buttons...

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"Saloon"]) {
        if (self.MOVING == NO) {
            self.SaloonWalk = YES;
            self.MOVING = YES;
        }
    }
```

The problem is when I click on the saloon, even though it scaled with the scene, My code still has the unscaled dimensions for it. So, if I click slightly below the Saloon it runs the above code, but if I click near the top of the Saloon nothing happens. I've done some searching and haven't found any help with scaling the area for touching a node with my newly scaled scene.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have subclassed SKSpriteNode to build your buttons and your touchesBegan Shown above is in your button subclass, you need to call the location for the parent:

```
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self.parent];
```

as locationInNode gives you the location in the coordinates of the node passed in.  If you are looking to find the button node, the touch object should be sent the locationInNode with the parent node of the object you're looking for.